# Is yearly naming for ECMAScript, retrospective?

Tags: javascript

From ES6 (ES2015) onwards versions of ECMAScript are named according to the year they were released. But is this retrospective?

Would ES5 be ES2009?

Comment: I think they just gave up on big number versions when they started doing more releases. I guess technically ES5 *is* ES2009 but I'm pretty sure most people would stare at you blankly if you use the latter to refer to the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply take a look at [the ES5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), which is still titled

```
Standard ECMA-262
5.1 Edition / June 2011
ECMAScript® Language Specification
```

whereas the newer ones (examples from [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0), [ES10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/)) are titled

```
Standard ECMA-262
6th Edition / June 2015
ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification
```

```
ECMA-262, 10th edition, June 2019
ECMAScript® 2019 Language Specification
```

No, adding years to the newer edition's titles does not change the naming in earlier editions.